# How to remove specific html tags with contents in php?

Tags: php, html, regex

I have some contents in string format include some unwanted html tags and its content. I am looking for a way to remove them but still could not find a perfect solution for the purpose.

**Method 1**

Normally, we use `strip_tags` to remove the tags but it reserves the text content inside the tag.

**Method 2**

Then I tried to use `preg_replace` to remove tags along with the content using pattern like `/<font[\s\S].*?<\/font>/`

**Test**

but in the real situation , tags are sometime embracing the same tags like

```
text to keep <span xxx="xxxx"><span xxx="xxx">unwanted text</span> unwanted text </span> text to keep ...<some other tags>
```

Using both method won't give the desired result.

**Method 1 Output**

`unwanted text unwanted text text to keep`

**Method 2 Output**

`unwanted text </span> text to keep`

What is the best way to archive this?

I am looking for a solution like this (I know this pattern is not working):

```
$remove_arr = [
   'span',
   'div',
   'strong'
]
foreach($remove_arr as $remove){
  $content = preg_replace("/<$remove.*?<\/$remove>/", '',$content);
}
```

Thank you guys in advanced!

**UPDATE**

The code is in a file called Collect.php

```
<?php
namespace app\common\model;
use think\Db;
use think\Cache;
use app\common\util\Pinyin;
use think\Request;

class Collect extends Base {
   //the code
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strip_tags()` has its limitations, and regular expressions are just not the tool to work effectively with arbitrary HTML strings (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/14853083))

You need to be working with something that understands HTML. i.e. [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). You could recurse down the tree finding the nodes you want, but fortunately PHP has [DOMXPath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) that will do it for you

This snippet will load a string into DOMDocument, search for and remove all the `<span>` elements, and return the remainder into a string:

```
$str = <<<HTML
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
text to keep <span xxx="xxxx"><span xxx="xxx">unwanted text</span> unwanted text </span> text to keep
</body>
</html>
HTML;
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($str);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach($xpath->evaluate("//span") as $node) {
    echo 'Removing: '.$node->nodeValue."<br>";
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
$output = $doc->saveHTML();
echo htmlspecialchars($output);
```

Output:

```
Removing: unwanted text unwanted text
Removing: unwanted text
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body> text to keep text to keep </body> </html>
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/6m0e2

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I really think this could help. However, I met a problem when testing it. It shows `Fatal error: Class 'app\common\model\DOMDocument' not found`. I use a custom CMS built with thinkphp. I think it might be due to I didn't use the correct namespace? Or do I need to have some specific php extension to use DOMDocument? I search for some article. Someone said it needs php-xml and some said it needs php-dom. It seems I have both extension enabled. Please advise. Thank you again for the reply.

Comment: `DOMDocument` is situated in the root namespace so you would need to do `$dom = new \DomDocument();` or place an `use` statement above you class definition

Comment: @philip If PHP is complaining that DOMDocument  is not found then you'll need to install it on your system. I use Ubuntu and their package listings suggest the DOMDocument is in both php-xml and php-dom. It shouldn't matter which you install. This should be true for all Debian-related distributions, but other flavours may package their software differently.

Comment: @Tangentially Perpendicular Thank you for your answer. It solved the problem. Glad I have learned some xpath previously. Now its useful haha.

@DarkBee And thank you for the explanation. Adding \ before DomDocument(); helped. If I would like to use `use`. What should be the path? My php folder is outside the website folder.

Comment: `use DomDocument;` will suffice