# Get spcific parts of post wordpress

Tags: wordpress, posts

So what im trying to do is to only get specific parts of my post to be shown.

Post Eg.

```
<h3>Heading</h3>
<p>Text about heading<p>
<h3>Heading-2</h3>
<p>Some other text about heading<p>
```

now what I want to be shown on the frontend is for e.g. only the paragraphs and not the heading.

Eg what to be shown.

```
<p>Text about heading</p>
<p>Some other text about heading</p>
```

Tried googling but couldn't really find something that matches my problem. Maybe I was asking the wrong questions.

Comment: You should indicate how you're inputting the data on the backend (Block Editor, ACF fields, Classic Editor, etc.) and you're showing your post content on the front-end.

Comment: Im adding the data from the posts section in the backend and I'm currently not displaying in the front-end since that's what my question is about.

Comment: When you say "shown", do you just mean "visible"? If so, you should be able to generally target it with a CSS `display: none;`, assuming your theme has a container that wraps the main content. If you are talking about removing it from the HTML, I'd recommend an HTML-aware parser. Here's an [example removing `<span>` tags and their contents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68644034/231316) that you can adapt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want specific part of your posts to be displayed, the easier and more logical way is to simply add a new field in your posts (perhaps use ACF it has a free for ever version or something similar) and then in the frontend get your field (in case you are using ACF) using for example this:

```
echo esc_attr( get_field( 'mycustom_field_name' ) );
```

An other solution would be to simple apply a css rule for anything you do not want to be visible, make sure to include the post class in the body of your posts to avoid hiding elements in other pages/post types.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for. Appreciate your help.